# ZeroMQ for basic signalling?

Tags: zeromq

Maybe I missed this in the docs, but how do you use ZeroMQ for simple signaling between multiple nodes? Something like REQ to REQ, with no REPs.

Example: I sometimes want to tell all other nodes to invalidate cache pages or notify them that something happened.

- Request-reply won't work because I don't want the requester to block waiting for an empty response. I want to allow multiple signals to build up at the server.
- Publish-subscribe feels wrong because I'd have to subscribe to everything, and start two sockets, one for each direction of communication.
- PAIRs don't support automatically reconnecting and have other limitations.

Is pub-sub the best way to go? Or am I better just to use a traditional socket, write to both ends, and handle disconnections/reconnecting?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a dealer socket in your client side and a dealer socket on your server side. If you want to be able to send message to a specific node from the server side, then you better use a router socket in the server.